# Add new StructField to Array of StructFields in scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, struct, schema

I have a schema for json data defined as

```
val gpsSchema: StructType = 
  StructType(Array(
    StructField("Name",StringType,true),
    StructField("GPS", ArrayType(
      StructType(Array(
          StructField("TimeStamp",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("Longitude", DoubleType, true),
          StructField("Latitude",DoubleType,true)
          )),true),true)))
```

**data**

```
{"Name":"John","GPS":[{"TimeStamp": 1605449171.259277, "Longitude": -76.463684, "Latitude": 40.787052}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449175.743052, "Longitude": -76.464046, "Latitude": 40.787038}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449180.932659, "Longitude": -76.464465, "Latitude": 40.787022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449187.288478, "Longitude": -76.464977, "Latitude": 40.787054}]}
```

How can I add a new StructField "ID" (uid) to the GPS array such that

**before**

```
[{"TimeStamp": 1605449171.259277, "Longitude": -76.463684, "Latitude": 40.787052}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449175.743052, "Longitude": -76.464046, "Latitude": 40.787038}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449180.932659, "Longitude": -76.464465, "Latitude": 40.787022}, 
{"TimeStamp": 1605449187.288478, "Longitude": -76.464977, "Latitude": 40.787054}]
```

**after**

```
[{"ID": 123,"TimeStamp": 1605449171.259277, "Longitude": -76.463684, "Latitude": 40.787052}, 
{"ID": 123, "TimeStamp": 1605449175.743052, "Longitude": -76.464046, "Latitude": 40.787038}, 
{"ID": 123,"TimeStamp": 1605449180.932659, "Longitude": -76.464465, "Latitude": 40.787022}, 
{"ID": 123,"TimeStamp": 1605449187.288478, "Longitude": -76.464977, "Latitude": 40.787054}]
```

One way is to flatten the nested fields, add the new column "ID", use struct("ID","TimeStamp","Longitude","Latitude") and perform a collect_list as below:-

```
Dataframe
.withColumn( "ID", uuid())
.withColumn("GPS", explode($"GPS"))
.select($"ID", $"Name", $"GPS.*")
.select($"Name" ,struct("ID","TimeStamp","Longitude","Latitude").alias("field"))
.groupBy("Name").agg(collect_list($"field"))
```

This will be an expensive operation if the are a large number of elements in the array which may cause the spark driver to crash

Is there another way to just add in the "ID" field within the GPS array of the existing schema?

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `explode`, `groupBy` & `collect_list`, Try below code.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- GPS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- TimeStamp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val addCol = udf((id:String,json:String) => {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
    compact(parse(json).extract[List[Map[String,String]]].map(m => m ++ Map("id" -> id)))
})


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

addCol: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = SparkUserDefinedFunction($Lambda$3755/1542889653@a4d1d2c,StringType,List(Some(class[value[0]: string]), Some(class[value[0]: string])),None,true,true)

scala> df.withColumn("GPS_New",addCol(uuid,to_json($"GPS"))).show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|GPS                                                                                                                                                                                     |Name|GPS_New                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[40.787052, -76.463684, 1.605449171259277E9], [40.787038, -76.464046, 1.605449175743052E9], [40.787022, -76.464465, 1.605449180932659E9], [40.787054, -76.464977, 1.605449187288478E9]]|John|[{"Latitude":"40.787052","Longitude":"-76.463684","TimeStamp":"1.605449171259277E9","id":"123"},{"Latitude":"40.787038","Longitude":"-76.464046","TimeStamp":"1.605449175743052E9","id":"123"},{"Latitude":"40.787022","Longitude":"-76.464465","TimeStamp":"1.605449180932659E9","id":"123"},{"Latitude":"40.787054","Longitude":"-76.464977","TimeStamp":"1.605449187288478E9","id":"123"}]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas the "GPS_New" column from the function is also making the values as strings as seen in double quotes. How can it be changed like below 
  "id":"123",
  "timestamp": 1586966278.699324,
  "Longitude": -74.05301617127735,
  "Latitude": 41.94429181915331

Comment: using `addCol` udf, inside that I am converting into json.

Comment: In your example for "GPS_New" the addcol function is converting the double types to string {"Latitude":"40.787054","Longitude":"-76.464977","TimeStamp":"1.605449187288478E9","id":"123"}. Is there a way to keep the timestamp, latitude, longitude as double type 
 and id as string only